Is Frege's axiom of unrestricted comprehension actually true after all?
Consider the following demonstration whose first line is the assumption called the axiom of unrestricted comprehension.

∀F∃y ∀x[x ∈ y iff F(x)] [OSC1]
∀F∃y [α ∈ y iff F(α)] [UI]
∃y [α ∈ y iff α ∉ α] [UI]
α ∈ x1 iff α ∉ α [EI]

The only way to get Russell's paradox is if alpha must be a general constant.  But, in universal Instantiation, alpha is either a general constant or a specific constant.  Therefore

∀x[x=α] ∨ ∃! x[x=α]

If ∀x[x=α] then you get Russell's paradox.  But you aren't done, because line 5 is a disjunction, so

∃! x[x=α] [5; DS]

Thus alpha is a specific constant.
If alpha equals x1 then you get Russell's paradox, so

x1 ≠ α

[α ∈ x1 iff α ∉ α] ∧ x1 ≠ α [4,7; conj]

∀F∃y[α ∈ y iff F(α) ∧ y ≠ α]


Since alpha is a specific constant you can't universally generalize on it, you can only existentially generalize on it.

∃x ∀F∃y[x ∈ y iff F(x) ∧ y ≠ x]

Closing the scope of the first assumption, line 1 implies line 10.
The point is, Russell's paradox is not a consequence of Gottlob Frege's axiom of unrestricted comprehension.  This isn't surprising since Russell didn't understand the nuances of universal Instantiation in 1901. It wasn't until 1929 that Goedel proved the first order function calculus is complete, and I'm not sure if he knew the nuances of Universal Instantiation.  In fact Leon Henkin's proof FOL is complete is the one I'm familiar with, and that proof came out in 1949. And it isn't clear to me that Henkin knew the nuances of Universal Instantiation either.
What do you think?

Step 5 makes no sense. ∀x[x=α] says that your domain contains only a single value. ∃! x[x=α] is a consequence of the meaning of equivalence so it's always true for every value.

Even assuming that unrestricted comprehension does not derive Russell's paradox, how does that make it "true"? Plenty of things that do not derive contradictions are not true, and there are plenty of paradoxes besides Russell's.

Regarding the puzzling statement: "since Russell didn't understand the nuances of universal Instantiation in 1901", see Bertrand Russell, Mathematical Logic as based on the Theory of Types (1908), II All and Any for the clear discussion of the interplay between Instantiation and Generalization.

@davidgudeman, for all x: x= a doesn't say the domain contains a single thing.  It says: x1=a &x2=a&x3=a&... The transitive property doesn't apply here because a isn't a specific constant, it's an arbitrary constant.  I know how to prove transitivity of equality using Hao Wang's axiom of Identity, and the proof only works if the three symbols x,y,z in if x=y &y=z then x=z, are SPECIFIC CONSTANTS.  The statement there exists a unique X, such that x=a, isn't necessarily true.  It's false if a is a general constant.  C is a general constant iff for all x: x=C.

@conifold, you are 100% correct.  Even assuming Russell's paradox doesn't follow from unrestricted comprehension, it does NOT follow that unrestricted comprehension is true.  It's an assumption in line 1.  What the derivation shows is it's not necessarily false.  Frege considered it intuitive, and chose it as an axiom.  My view is it's intuitively true, I asked for other views.  I guess my point is, there can be a consistent Axiomatic Set Theory with Frege's unrestricted comprehension axiom.

@mauro, I read II All and Any, and Russell uses the vague word always to understand for all x: P(x).  It doesn't appear he understood universal Instantiation based on his use of the word 'always'.

Your terms "specific constant" and "arbitrary constant" are not part of standard logic. A name can be a constant in which case it represents a specific single value from the domain or it can be a variable in which case it is implicitly universally quantified. If α is a constant, then ∀x[x=α] says that every value in the domain is equal to one specific value, α, which means that there is only one value, α, in the domain. If α is a variable then the formula is equivalent to ∀α∀x[x=α] which can only be true if the domain has one or fewer elements.

"C is a general constant iff for all x: x=C" I don't know what logical traditional you are referring to here, if any, but it's not part of standard predicate logic with equality.

@david, what is x in the equation x^2-1=0?  Is it a name, a variable, or something else?

It's algebra, which is different from logic.



∀F∃y ∀x[x ∈ y iff F(x)] [OSC1]
∀F∃y [α ∈ y iff F(α)] [UI]
∃y [α ∈ y iff α ∉ α] [UI]
α ∈ x1 iff α ∉ α [EI]


Step 2 is not how universal instantiation works. It only lets you remove the outermost ∀, but you're trying to use it on the innermost ∀. Here's a better version of what you're trying to do:

∀F∃y ∀x[x ∈ y iff F(x)]
∃y ∀x[x ∈ y iff x ∉ x] (UI, where F(x) is x ∉ x)
∀x[x ∈ S iff x ∉ x] (EI, choosing the unused letter S)
S ∈ S iff S ∉ S (UI, substituting S for x).


if there exists x, such that for any y[ P(x,y) ], then for any y there exists x, such that [ P(x,y)] so you can universally instantiate using the innermost universal quantifier.  Your way requires you to instantiate F with an expression containing a variable, and I wanted to avoid that.  But your line 4 doesn't follow from line 3 because in universal Instantiation, the constant you instantiate the variable with isn't necessarily a general constant, it's possible it's a specific constant.  I'm using modal logic to understand this.

@leepappas (1) "if there exists x, such that for any y[ P(x,y) ], then for any y there exists x, such that [ P(x,y)]" - this is true but the converse is not true; it is not the case that "if for any y there exists x such that P(x, y) implies there exists x such that for any y P(x, y)." By removing the innermost ∀ you are obtaining a weaker expression, not an equivalent one, which is why you have trouble reaching Russell's paradox afterwards. (2) Also even if it's valid it's just not the inference rule of UI: formally UI works on the outermost quantifier.

(3) Line 4 does follow from line 3 by UI. UI in FOL doesn't care about modal logic. We're not using modal logic. Frege worked before modern modal logic. UI just allows you to replace ∀xA with A{x -> y}, where A{x -> y} is the result of replacing every free x variable in A with another variable y. There are no requirements on x or y.

you need modal logic to understand universal Instantiation.  Suppose you know for any x[P(x)].  That means P(x1)&P(x2)&P(x3)&.... You need to insist your Instantiation constant y is a general constant, to infer P(y).  But that is a necessity condition which means you're using modal logic.  It is possible that y is a specific constant.  Thus you can't infer y is necessarily a general constant.

@leepappas This distinction "general constant" or "specific constant" is not made in first order logic. Nor is there any concept of possible worlds.

if you understand the meanings of general constant and specific constant you will see the distinction is necessary for FOL.  C is a general constant iff forall x[x=C],  C is a specific constant iff there is a unique thing x, such that x=C.  Suppose for all x[P(x)].  You can Instantiatie x with a specific constant or an arbitrary constant.

@leepappas It would be a very unusual logic to have a C for which for all x, x=C. This would mean you have a universe of only one object.

,the transitive property of equality isn't true generally.  In the case where a is a general constant and x1=a&x2=a&x3=a&... You can't infer x1=x2=x3=... Because transitivity of equality doesn't apply.  Thus, there can be an infinite number of individuals.


Consider the following demonstration whose first line is the assumption called the axiom of unrestricted comprehension.


∀F∃y ∀x[x ∈ y iff F(x)] [OSC1]
∀F∃y [α ∈ y iff F(α)] [UI]
∃y [α ∈ y iff α ∉ α] [UI]
α ∈ x1 iff α ∉ α [EI]


The only way to get Russell's paradox is if alpha must be a general constant. But, in universal Instantiation, alpha is either a general constant or a specific constant. Therefore

Your analysis is mistaken, α must be a what you call a general constant. Kit Fine refers to arbitrary objects, so the term 'arbitrary constant ' is preferable, since it resembles Fine's terminology.
Use these definitions
Definition
C is a specific constant iff ∃!x[x=C]
C is an arbitrary constant iff ∀x[x=C]
You should instantiate from left to right, as the other responses suggest.

∀F∃y ∀x[x ∈ y iff F(x)] [OSC1]
∃y ∀x[x ∈ y iff x ∉ x] [1;UI]
∀x[x ∈ A iff x ∉ x] [2;EI]

If your domain of discourse is the set of all things, then since a set is a kind of thing, you can instantiate x with A, to get Russell's paradox

A ∈ A iff A ∉ A [3;UI]

Here you instantiated x with what you call a specific constant, and that's ok.  But you could have instantiated x with an arbitrary constant α, and reasoned as follows

α ∈ A iff α ∉ α [3;UI]

Here, ∀x[x=α] is necessarily true. Now α can denote any thing, therefore it can denote what A denotes. So by UI
A = α
Now, by substitution you get
A ∈ A iff A ∉ A
There's nothing wrong with the definitions of arbitrary constant and specific constant, but in universal instantiation the special symbol α must be an arbitrary constant.  Modal logic must be applied correctly.
